# Adding to a string array alphabetically

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, sorting

I'm looking for a way to add a string (from a cell) to a string array alphabetically.

For instance:

```
string array = {"apple", "banana", "orange"}
```

add `"cherry"`:

```
string array = {"apple", "banana", "cherry", "orange"}
```

Hence if I do `sheets(1).range("A1").value = new string array`, the entire array will be in one cell.

I found a function online that sorts selected cells alphabetically, but not sure if it helps in my instance.

```
Function Alphabetize(vStrings As Variant, separator As String) As String

    Dim v As Variant, vSorted As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, n As Long
    Dim bDone As Boolean

    For Each v In vStrings
        n = n + 1
    Next
    ReDim vSorted(1 To n)
    ReDim pos(1 To n)
    For Each v In vStrings
         i = i + 1
         vSorted(i) = v
    Next
    For j = 2 To n
         bDone = True
         For i = 2 To n
             If vSorted(i) < vSorted(i - 1) Then
                 v = vSorted(i - 1)
                 vSorted(i - 1) = vSorted(i)
                 vSorted(i) = v
                 bDone = False
             End If
         Next
         If bDone Then Exit For
    Next
    For i = 1 To n
         If vSorted(i) <> "" Then
             If i = 1 Then
                 Alphabetize = separator & vSorted(i)
             Else
                 If vSorted(i) <> vSorted(i - 1) Then Alphabetize = Alphabetize & separator & vSorted(i)
             End If
         End If
    Next
    Alphabetize = Mid$(Alphabetize, 2)
End Function
```

Comment: Where are you populating `vStrings` to begin with and where are you getting the *'cherry'* value to add to it?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `System.Collections.SortedList` class from the `.NET` library, if you want. Then there's no need to worry about sorting.

```
Dim objList As Object
Set objList = CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList")
objList.Add "apple",  ""
objList.Add "banana", ""
objList.Add "orange", ""
objList.Add "cherry", ""

Dim i As Long
For i = 0 To objList.Count - 1
    Debug.Print objList.GetKey(i)
Next
```

Prints:

```
apple
banana
cherry
orange
```

If you want to combine the values into a string, just concatenate them as you loop through the values or you can transfer to an array and use `Join` to create the string:

```
ReDim a(objList.Count - 1) As String
Dim i As Long

For i = 0 To objList.Count - 1
    a(i) = objList.GetKey(i)
Next

' Combine strings into the format: {"string1", "string2", "stringN"}
Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = "{""" & Join(a, """, """) & """}"
```

Comment: This is such a great answer. I've read a bit about using .Net classes and would like to know more, such as which ones are available, generally and on any given computer. Do you have any resources to recommend.

Comment: @DougGlancy There's an [article on The Scripting Guys blog](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.01.heyscriptingguy.aspx) that can help get you started. I'm not sure there's a comprehensive list of .NET classes with COM wrappers but that article should give you some tips to get started.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear where the declaration or assignment of `vStrings` and *'cherry*' are  but here is a sub calling the function that appends the array and returns a delimited list (single text value) to Sheet1's A1.

```
Sub main()
    Dim string_array As Variant, new_string As String

    string_array = Array("apple", "banana", "orange")
    new_string = "cherry"

    Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value = add_and_alphabetize(string_array, new_string, sDELIM:=Chr(44))

End Sub

Function add_and_alphabetize(vSTR As Variant, sSTR As String, _
         Optional sDELIM As String = ";", Optional bDESC As Boolean = False)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, vTMP As Variant

    If CBool(Len(sSTR)) Then
        ReDim Preserve vSTR(LBound(vSTR) To UBound(vSTR) + 1)
        vSTR(UBound(vSTR)) = sSTR
    End If

    For i = LBound(vSTR) To UBound(vSTR) - 1
        For j = i To UBound(vSTR)
            If (vSTR(i) < vSTR(j) And bDESC) Or (vSTR(i) > vSTR(j) And Not bDESC) Then
                vTMP = vSTR(j)
                vSTR(j) = vSTR(i)
                vSTR(i) = vTMP
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    add_and_alphabetize = Join(vSTR, sDELIM)
End Function
```

I've added options to specify the delimiter character (defaulted as a semi-colon) and change the order of the sort.